# How to traverse tree with specific properties

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

I have a tree as shown below.

- Red means it has a certain property, unfilled means it doesn't have it. I want to minimise the `Red` checks.

  1. If `Red` than all Ancestors are also `Red` (and should not be checked again).
  2. If `Not Red` than all Descendants are `Not Red`.
- The depth of the tree is `d`.
- The width of the tree is `n`.
- Note that children nodes have value larger than the parent.

  - Example: In the tree below,

    - Node '0' has children [1, 2, 3],
    - Node '1' has children [2, 3],
    - Node '2' has children [3] and
    - Node '4' has children [] (No children).
  - Thus children can be constructed as:

    ```
    if vertex.depth > 0:
        vertex.children = [Vertex(parent=vertex, val=child_val, depth=vertex.depth-1, n=n) for child_val in xrange(self.val+1, n)]
    else:
        vertex.children = []
    ```

Here is an example tree:

[image: The tree]

I am trying to count the number of `Red` nodes. Both the depth and the width of the tree will be large. So I want to do a sort of Depth-First-Search and additionally use the properties 1 and 2 from above.

How can I design an algorithm to do traverse that tree?

PS: I tagged this [python] but any outline of an algorithm would do.

### Update & Background

1. I want to minimise the property checks.
2. The property check is checking the connectedness of a bipartite graph constructed from  my tree's path. 
   *Example*:

   - The bottom-left node in the example tree has *path* = [0, 1].
   - Let the bipartite graph have sets `R` and `C` with size `r` and `c`. (Note, that the width of the tree is `n=r*c`).
   - From the *path* I get to the edges of the graph by starting with a full graph and removing edges (x, y) for all values in the path as such: `x, y = divmod(value, c)`.

The two rules for the property check come from the connectedness of the graph: 
- If the graph is connected with edges [a, b, c] removed, then it must also be connected with [a, b] removed (rule 1). 
- If the graph is disconnected with edges [a, b, c] removed, then it must also be disconnected with additional edge d removed [a, b, c, d] (rule 2).

#### Update 2

So what I really want to do is check all combinations of picking d elements out of [0..n]. The tree structure somewhat helps but even if I got an optimal tree traversal algorithm, I still would be checking too many combinations. (I noticed that just now.)

Let me explain. Assuming I need checked [4, 5] (so 4 and 5 are removed from bipartite graph as explained above, but irrelevant here.). If this comes out as "Red", my tree will prevent me from checking [4] only. That is good. However, I should also mark off [5] from checking.

How can I change the structure of my tree (to a graph, maybe?) to further minimise my number of checks?

Comment: Shouldn't node 1 be red by property (1) because of node 3, or node 3 be not red by property (2) because of node 1?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake when drawing the tree. Will fix.

Comment: How is the tree represented?  Can you access any node you want, or just the root?

Comment: I can represent the tree in any way I want. A node can be defined as [a, b, c] where a < b < c. But do I need to construct the tree first, or can I actually not construct the tree and just look at a few nodes?

Comment: I implemented two algorithms. One tests the nodes from the top (property 2) and another which tests them from the bottom (property 1). They are both correct but too slow to run with width n=25 and depth d=13.

Comment: What is the average percentage of red elements in the tree? The correct answer is heavily dependent on this.

Comment: Where is the data in the tree coming from, and what format is it in? Is checking the property an expensive operation that should be minimized?

Comment: Is the property a mathematical property of the values of the nodes (for example, value > n)? You've said that the value of a node is less than the values of its children, but we have no idea how to connect that to the rest of the problem.

Comment: Based on the information here, it would appear that there are cases where you always have to check a substantial fraction of the nodes - e.g. if about half the nodes are red. The only way I can see to avoid these and get a decent speed-up is if there is something we can deduce about how or why the tree is constructed. Is there anything you can tell us about this, or are the bullet-points really all there is to say?

Comment: @llb I do not know the average percentage of red elements. What are the correct answers if red/total is either 0.2, 0.5 or 0.8? However, I would guess that the average depth that one needs to go down the tree is around 0.5-0.7 of the total depth.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, checking the property of the operation is expensive and should be minimised. The property of the node is a function of the values of the path. But I don't think a closed form expression exists. I will update the question regarding this.

Comment: @user2357112 I will update the question on how to generate the tree. I thought saying that value < parent.value is enough to construct it but surely it is not clear enough. Given value of node and tree-width n, the children's values are `[child_val for child_val in xrange(value+1, n)]`.

Comment: @mcdowella I answered some other comments and updated my question, does the additional information help?

Comment: When checking the connectedness, what is the initial value of sets R and C ?

Comment: `R or C = set([0..r or c])`

Comment: No, I don't mean their size but contents.

Comment: Yes, the contents go from 0 up to r-1 in increments of 1.

Comment: So, in one sentence, you're trying to enumerate connected bipartite graphs with one part having r vertices and one having c?

Comment: Yes and I am only interested in the number of graphs that exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variant of the deletion–contraction algorithm for evaluating the Tutte polynomial (evaluated at (1,2), gives the total number of spanning subgraphs) on the complete bipartite graph K_{r,c}.

In a sentence, the idea is to order the edges arbitrarily, enumerate spanning trees, and count, for each spanning tree, how many spanning subgraphs of size r + c + k have that minimum spanning tree. The enumeration of spanning trees is performed recursively. If the graph G has exactly one vertex, the number of associated spanning subgraphs is the number of self-loops on that vertex choose k. Otherwise, find the minimum edge that isn't a self-loop in G and make two recursive calls. The first is on the graph G/e where e is contracted. The second is on the graph G-e where e is deleted, but only if G-e is connected.

Comment: Thanks for giving me something to read up about. Most concepts in your answer are new to me, so I will need some time to evaluate all this.

Answer (score 1):

Python is close enough to pseudocode.

```
class counter(object):
    def __init__(self, ival = 0):
        self.count = ival

    def count_up(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count

def old_walk_fun(ilist, func=None):
    def old_walk_fun_helper(ilist, func=None, count=0):
        tlist = []
        if(isinstance(ilist, list) and ilist):
            for q in ilist:
                tlist += old_walk_fun_helper(q, func, count+1)
        else:
            tlist = func(ilist)
        return [tlist] if(count != 0) else tlist
    if(func != None and hasattr(func, '__call__')):
        return old_walk_fun_helper(ilist, func)
    else:
        return []

def walk_fun(ilist, func=None):
    def walk_fun_helper(ilist, func=None, count=0):
        tlist = []
        if(isinstance(ilist, list) and ilist):
            if(ilist[0] == "Red"): # Only evaluate sub-branches if current level is Red
                for q in ilist:
                    tlist += walk_fun_helper(q, func, count+1)
        else:
            tlist = func(ilist)
        return [tlist] if(count != 0) else tlist
    if(func != None and hasattr(func, '__call__')):
        return walk_fun_helper(ilist, func)
    else:
        return []

# Crude tree structure, first element is always its colour; following elements are its children
tree_list = \
["Red",
    ["Red", 
        ["Red", 
            []
        ], 
        ["White", 
            []
        ],
        ["White", 
            []
        ]
    ],
    ["White",
        ["White", 
            []
        ],
        ["White", 
            []
        ]
    ],
    ["Red", 
        []
    ]
]

red_counter = counter()
eval_counter = counter()
old_walk_fun(tree_list, lambda x: (red_counter.count_up(), eval_counter.count_up()) if(x == "Red") else eval_counter.count_up())
print "Unconditionally walking"
print "Reds found: %d" % red_counter.count
print "Evaluations made: %d" % eval_counter.count
print ""

red_counter = counter()
eval_counter = counter()
walk_fun(tree_list, lambda x: (red_counter.count_up(), eval_counter.count_up()) if(x == "Red") else eval_counter.count_up())
print "Selectively walking"
print "Reds found: %d" % red_counter.count
print "Evaluations made: %d" % eval_counter.count
print ""
```

Comment: By writing the tree down, this essentially does all the expensive checks of determining whether a Node is "Red" or "White". Is there a way to do it without specifying the tree before hand?

Comment: Instead of the tree containing strings simply saying "Red" or "White", they could instead be objects and every test of checking for "Red" would be done by some algorithm (whatever you have in mind).

Answer (score 0):

How hard are you working on making the test for connectedness fast?

To test a graph for connectedness I would pick edges in a random order and use union-find to merge vertices when I see an edge that connects them. I could terminate early if the graph was connected, and I have a sort of certificate of connectedness - the edges which connected two previously unconnected sets of vertices.

As you work down the tree/follow a path on the bipartite graph, you are removing edges from the graph. If the edge you remove is not in the certificate of connectedness, then the graph must still be connected - this looks like a quick check to me. If it is in the certificate of connectedness you could back up to the state of union/find as of just before that edge was added and then try adding new edges, rather than repeating the complete connectedness test.

Depending on exactly how you define a path, you may be able to say that extensions of that path will never include edges using a subset of vertices - such as vertices which are in the interior of the path so far. If edges originating from those untouchable vertices are sufficient to make the graph connected, then no extension of the path can ever make it unconnected. Then at the very least you just have to count the number of distinct paths. If the original graph is regular I would hope to find some dynamic programming recursion that lets you count them without explicitly enumerating them.